# LISTAGG Oracle to join multiple rows with related records

Tags: oracle11g

Anyone can help to join all the rows with the same Name with dash if the same string and if different join with pipe, I tried listagg function but I don’t know where to put the pipe.

```
SELECT NAME, ID
       LISTAGG(DIRECTION, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID)
FROM DUAL
GROUP BY NAME, ID

Data:

NAME ID DIRECTION
A    1  AAA-BBB
A    2  BBB-CCC
A    3  DDD-CCC
B    1  ZZZ-AAA
C    1  AAA-CCC
C    2  CCC-BBB
C    3  BBB-CCC

Desired:
NAME ID DIRECTION
A    1  AAA-BBB-BBB-CCC|DDD-CCC
B    1  ZZZ-AAA
C    1  AAA-CCC-CCC-BBB-BBB-CCC
```

Comment: Your title says Oracle but you've tagged *MySql* - please correct your description / tags

Comment: Sorry Sir, it should have been Oracle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LEAD` to compare the next direction and append the appropriate delimiter rather than trying to do it with the `LISTAGG` argument:

```sql
SELECT name,
       MIN(id) AS id,
       LISTAGG(
         direction
         ||
         CASE
         WHEN next_direction IS NULL
         THEN NULL
         WHEN SUBSTR(direction, -3) = next_direction
         THEN '-'
         ELSE '|'
         END
       ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS direction
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LEAD(SUBSTR(direction, 1, 3)) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id)
           AS next_direction
  FROM   table_name t
)
GROUP BY NAME
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (NAME, ID, DIRECTION) AS
SELECT 'A', 1, 'AAA-BBB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, 'BBB-CCC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 3, 'DDD-CCC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, 'ZZZ-AAA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 1, 'AAA-CCC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 2, 'CCC-BBB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 3, 'BBB-CCC' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NAME | ID | DIRECTION |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 1 | AAA-BBB-BBB-CCC|DDD-CCC |
> | B | 1 | ZZZ-AAA |
> | C | 1 | AAA-CCC-CCC-BBB-BBB-CCC |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a0bea77dba55b095e6bf26add37c6211)*

Comment: Thank you sir. That’s what I am looking for.